# how to add cfnetwork & other frameworks to your project for asynchronous transmission - iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, asynchronous, cfnetwork

I am trying to add facility of asynchronous transmission in my project.

I want following in my application.

- A table view should load data through web service ( I can do )
- Each cell must have an image ( I can do )

But the problem is up to now I was using synchronous transmission.
i.e all data is loaded & then displayed including images.

Now, like apple store's table view images are loaded after sometimes.
I know that is asynchronous transmission.

Even I have tried to understand the pokeb-asi example.

But the problem is as follows.

" I am failure in adding all those frameworks & files ( which are necessary for asynchronous transmission ) in a new application of iPhone. "

Question is How to do this ?

Edit :

Frameworks are added successfully.

Now i have added ASINetworkQueue.h & m + ASINSStringAdditions.h & m & all the files to my project.

I am getting errors of this kind.

-[ASIHTTPRequest attemptToApplyProxyCredentialsAndResume] in ASIHTTPRequest.o

All the errors are of .o type.

_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags referenced from :
[Reachability remoteHostStatus] in Reachability.o

How to solve this erros ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to add `CFNetwork` to your project, double-click the Target in your Groups and Files list. Go to the General pane, and click the "+" for Linked Libraries. Choose CFNetwork. It will then link with your project.

Is there more to your question?

EDIT: Look up `SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags` in the docs. You will see it's part of `SystemConfiguration.framework`. You need to add that as well.